# How to map BAM file from hg38 to hg19 for GEDmatch kit creation?

Tags: autosomal-dna, gedmatch.com

I have a Whole Genome Sequence (WGS) test from Nebula which results in a hg38 BAM file.  I'd like to generate a kit on [GEDmatch.com](https://GEDmatch.com) which requires hg19 BAM together with the [WGS Extract tool](https://wgsextract.github.io/) suite to make an everything kit.

I can convert a BAM from hg19 to hg38 using ySeq.net's product [FASTQ Mapping to hg38](https://www.yseq.net/product_info.php?products_id=107732).

How can I map in reverse to go backwards from hg38 to hg19 so that I can ultimately create an everything [superkit](https://forums.gedmatch.com/BB/viewforum.php?f=28) for GEDmatch.com?

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, WGS extract is designed to generate a Combined file of ALL SNPs for GEDMATCH in Build 37 (hg19) format. It should read your Build 38 (hg38) BAM file and produce a file that can be uploaded to GEDMATCH.  You should use the "Everything" option.

[image]

The WGS Extract Manual states:

> If supplying a Build38 reference model mapped BAM, the tool uses (Py)Liftover to convert the coordinates of called SNP variant values to Build37. Build37 is what the microarray test file formats are defined in.  This liftover operation only takes a few minutes and causes the loss of 500 or so values (out of 600,000 or more) due to unmappable regions between Build models

For more information, see the WGS Extract Manual available here: https://wgsextract.github.io/

If the Combined file for GEDMATCH that WGS Extract produces from your BAM file is not accepted by GEDmatch, then you should contact the WGS Extract developers and let them know.

If all you want to do is realign your BAM from Build 38 (hg38) to Build 37 (hg19), WGS Extract will do that for you with its "BAM Realign" button:

[image]